# How do I prevent a UINavigationController from recognising swipes when my scroll view isn't at the far left?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

In my app, many of the view controllers have in their view a UIScrollView which can scroll horizontally, and they are in a UINavigationController stack.  Sometimes, when the user is scrolling left-to-right on these views they accidentally trigger the navigation controller's swipe gesture and pop the current controller off the stack.

The views of these controllers all descend from a common class.

What I'd like is that if the scroll view can be scrolled left-to-right, that happens every time; but if not then the nav controller's gesture is allowed to happen.

How can I achieve this centrally?  I'm happy to override UINavigationController or my common view class, but I don't want to have to add stuff to the viewWill/DidAppear/Disappear in every controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to [Pete Steinberger](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/smart-proxy-delegation/), first we create a proxy so we can intercept the nav controller's delegate messages:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface SGBGestureDelegateProxy : NSProxy <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>;

@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) id delegate;

- (id)initWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController delegate:(id)delegate;

@end

@implementation SGBGestureDelegateProxy

- (id)initWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController delegate:(id)delegate
{
    if (self)
    {
        _navigationController = navigationController;

        _delegate = delegate;
        objc_setAssociatedObject(delegate, _cmd, self, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return [self.delegate respondsToSelector:selector];
}

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return [self.delegate respondsToSelector:selector] ? self.delegate : self;
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)sel
{
    return [self.delegate methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    // ignore
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    UIView *topView = self.navigationController.topViewController.view;
    CGPoint topPoint = [touch locationInView:topView];

    for (UIView *view = [topView hitTest:topPoint withEvent:nil]; view; view = view.superview)
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
        if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] && scrollView.scrollEnabled && (scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0))
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return [self.delegate gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:touch];
}

@end
```

Then we insert our proxy into the nav controller's gesture recogniser in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    id delegate = self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate;
    id proxy = [[C360NavigationControllerGestureDelegateProxy alloc] initWithNavigationController:self delegate:delegate];
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = proxy;
}
```

...and we're done.  Whenever the user starts to swipe, the proxy intercepts `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` and returns NO if the swipe begins in a scroll view which is horizontally scrolled.  If the scroll view isn't scrolled, or if there is no scroll view, then the gesture is recognised as normal.